# Dockerfile using variable built using Shell Command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

To be more clear on the goal, let's use a better example, say I wanted a portable `.env` file which collects the host IP address and then uses that inside the `build` process. The `.env` file should dynamically generates the variable each build so that if the host IP changes, the build will adjust.

I'm trying to use my host OS version as a build variable for my dockerfile which is called by docker-compose. I also tried just inject the image line into docker-compose to no avail.

Something like this:

```
cat .env
VER="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep -o 'DISTRIB_RELEASE.*' |  cut -f2- -d=)"
#VER=18.04
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:${VER}
```

or I left that out of dockerfile and used

docker-compose:

```
image: ubuntu:${VER}
build: .
```

But i got an error about no build process, not sure it can work this way. Any idea how I would inject a variable built from tools into a docker-file like this? (And/or Docker-Compose for future projects).

Update: I tried the following but continue to get an error.

```
cat docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
 fileserver:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    hostname: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        VER: ${VERSION}
```

......

```
cat .env
#VERSION="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep -o 'DISTRIB_RELEASE.*' |  cut -f2- -d=)"
VERSION="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep -o 'DISTRIB_CODENAME.*' |  cut -f2- -d=)"
```

.......

```
cat Dockerfile
#ARG VER
#FROM ubuntu:${VER}
FROM ubuntu:bionic
```

.......

If I uncomment either or both line in the `Dockerfile` using the variable, I get error:

```
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu:${VER} ERROR: Service 'ubuntu' failed to build: invalid reference format
```

Comment: Why not just pick the latest LTS release `FROM ubuntu:20.04`?  There's no requirement that the container distribution match the host distribution, and there are enough changes between 2-yearly major releases that it'll be hard to make the rest of your image build work properly.

Comment: (Do not put both `build: .` and `image: ubuntu` in your `docker-compose.yml`.  This will cause it to overwrite the standard `ubuntu` image with what you built, which will cause trouble down the road.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to get into why. Because it is a requirement of my project. I'm just looking for a solution to this specific issue which I may end up using for other variables and want to stick to the task at hand.

Comment: I think you had missed using the `.env` file. A shell command is included inside the `.env` file, but that won't work as you expect. You need to build the image based on the host os version?

Comment: I didn't understand your `cat` line, now I see it injects the result of the command into the variable in the .env file, but now this `.env` file isn't "portable" because the result may be different on another distribution.

Comment: Not quite understand your requirement, but I think your problem could be reduce to "how to correctly generate the env file base on your request". If the correct version is populated into the `.env` file, docker should build the image with your requested version...

Answer (score 7):

`ARG` is your friend.

- [Dockerfile ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)
- [Docker compose args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)

#### Dockerfile

```
ARG VER=latest
FROM ubuntu:${VER}
```

The above dockerfile defines a build argument named `VER`, which is default to `latest`.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  demo:
    image: enix223/demo
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        VER: ${VERSION}
```

We substitute image build arg `VER` with environment variable `VERSION`.

#### Start container using shell env variable

```
VERSION="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep -o 'DISTRIB_RELEASE.*' |  cut -f2- -d=)" docker-compose up -d
```

#### Start container using `.env` file

```
cat > .env << EOF
VERSION="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep -o 'DISTRIB_RELEASE.*' |  cut -f2- -d=)"
EOF

docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: I don't want to use global variables (call docker-compose with extra arguments from CLI) or set the tag statically. It should be generated via my regular tools dynamically used in the dockerfile/docker-compose.

Comment: you can create `.env` file with `VERSION` variable included. `.env` file takes the same effect as the shell environment variable.

Comment: yes, but you can use `ARG` to pass env variable to your Dockerfile, I have updated my answer to use `.env` file instead.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers would you please update this post with the code you have tried?

Comment: Unless somebody shows me a way to accomplish what I want, the bounty is yours. At least with your method, I don't have to edit both the Dockerfile and .env. I'd rather keep all variables in the `.env` file right?! Some are related to the `docker-compose` others the `DockerFile`